# Boxplot only display points

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a rather mysterious problem when I try to do a simple boxplot with

```
boxplot(data$sex,data$freq)
```

but I'm unable to display box plot, and I cannot figure out why. 
The type of my variable are respectively factor and numeric, and the dataset is composed of 40.000 observations.

[image: Boxplot]

Can you help me please?

Comment: You might want to log transform your data to better see their distribution.

Comment: There are plenty of zeros there, so I wouldn't use logarithm...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/207973)

Comment: Forget the boxplot for a moment, and try summarizing the freq variable for each value of sex.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However the OP does not explicitly state that the low values displayed by the box plot are true zeroes. I thought that the log transform together with the other answers could 'help' the user as they states. Finally I don't have the feeling that I ask for further clarification in my answer.

Comment: @leoburgy I have converted your post to a comment since it's a potentially useful piece of advice, but doesn't directly address the question (why the boxplots look as they do rather than whatever the OP expected them to look like)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `boxplot` turns into points all outliers, which are defined as the datapoints that are farther that 1.5*IQR from box (IQR = Quartile3-Quartile1). So probably almost all observations with `sex=1` are outliers in above sense.

Factor by which IQR is multiplied to obtain range of non-outliers is determined by `range` argument of `boxplot` function. Try experimenting with it. Plus, setting `range=0` will force `boxplot` to treat all observations as non-outliers (whiskers will show min and max then).

Answer (score 4):

It seems that almost all values in group 1 equal zero, with a few positive values above the 75 percentile. So there is nothing wrong with your plot.